# Why the plots of a second-order intensity correlation function appear both Bunching and Antibunching?

Tags: quantum-optics

[image]

This second-order correlation function is calculated based on a single atom in a cavity, driven by classical light source,under the condition of two photons resonance.

When I plotted it in Mathematica, I found that when the two-photon resonance is driven, bunching and antibunching both occur, depending on "g",which is the strength of the driving.

I thought only anti bunching would occur, because the system is a quantum-sized system and all the phenomena happened in a microscopic way.

Why bunching effect still happens in a quantum-sized cavity? Why it depends on the driving strength to get results of bunching or anti bunching?

Comment: Could you provide a reference? Otherwise it's hard to comprehend how to arrive at $g^{(2)}$ of exactly this form.